# store the result of the a dynamic pivot to a temp table

Tags: sql, dynamic, tabs, pivot, temp

I need to store the result of the following dynamic pivot to a temp table. Any suggesiotns?

```
DECLARE @serviceid int = 66;  
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);  
WITH  E(n) AS(  SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n) ), 
cteTally(n) AS(  SELECT TOP(SELECT /*TOP 1*/ COUNT(*) cnt   
FROM #T   WHERE serviceid = @serviceid--Comment this and uncomment the other part to use the full table.  /*GROUP BY serviceid   
ORDER BY cnt DESC*/) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n  
FROM E a, E b ) 
SELECT @SQL =   N'WITH CTE AS(' + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N'SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY serviceid ORDER BY serviceid) AS row_num' + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N'FROM #T' 
+ CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N'WHERE serviceid = @serviceid' + CHAR(10)  + N')' + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) 
+ N'SELECT serviceid' + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N',ProgramId' + CHAR(10)  
+ (SELECT CHAR(9) + ',MAX( CASE WHEN row_num = ' + CAST( n AS nvarchar(3)) 
+ ' THEN Firstbilleddate END) AS Firstbilleddate' + CAST( n AS nvarchar(3)) 
+ CHAR(10)  FROM cteTally  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')  
+ (SELECT CHAR(9) + ',MAX( CASE WHEN row_num = ' + CAST( n AS nvarchar(3)) + ' THEN CoveragePlanName END) AS CoveragePlanName' 
+ CAST( n AS nvarchar(3)) + CHAR(10)  FROM cteTally 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')  
+ CHAR(9) + N',SUM( ChargeAmount) AS ChargeAmount' + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N',SUM( AdjustmentAmount) AS AdjustmentAmount' 
+ CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N',SUM( PaymentAmount) AS PaymentAmount' + CHAR(10)  + N'FROM CTE' + CHAR(10)  + N'GROUP BY serviceid' 
+ CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + N',ProgramId;' + CHAR(10);  PRINT @SQL; EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@serviceid int', @serviceid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to use an OPENROWSET and execute your dynamic sql query there. You would need to pass your dynamic SQL (including variables) as a string.

Have a look at [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)